# UDR (UART data register)issues

Tags: interface, microcontroller, avr, uart

I can't understand the meaning of the following "The USART Transmit Data buffer register (TXB) and the USART Receive Data buffer register (RXB) share the same I/O address" there is two data register .how they share the same address ?

Answer (score 3):

Now it's clear 
[image]
From the diagram you see that The transmitter and receiver share the UDR (UART Data Register). Actually they only share the UDR address: The "real" register is divided into the transmitter and receiver register so that received data cannot overwrite data being written into the transmit register. Consequently you can't read back data you wrote into the transmitter register.

Answer (score 1):

The register address is the same for both TXB and RBX and the actual addressed register is determined by the modality in which the UART is (reading or writing mode). This is depended on the actual implementation, but usually it consist in setting one or two more pins.

Comment: thanks for your replay but according to your answer as i understand UART will work as half duplex and as i know UART work as full duplex

Comment: Yes, but UART has two interfaces, one with the CPU and one with the rest of the world, that work with different clocks. The CPU has a much faster clock and can access a register at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider UDR register as the buffer between TXD and RXD registers.
As you know UART is sent bit by bit in the bus, While recieving the bits is entering the RXD register, when all the byte is being recieved it copied to UDR register and the flag is raised, now you should read the UDR register and if you write to it you will lose the recieved byte!!

By the same way in transmission, you write the a byte in UDR then it moved to TXD then output from registerbit by bit and the UDR is empty during transmission.

That's why there is interrupt for UDR, when the UDR becomes empty, and interrupt for TXD, when trasnmission is completed.